# Can you remount /tmp partition to exec while live?

Tags: mount, exec, tmp

I have a server I need to re mount the /tmp partition to run exec.

The code I want to use is:

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

Run the program that needs it.

Than change it back.

```
mount -o remount,noexec /tmp
```

This is production server so I'm really worried about un mounting /tmp or changing the mount.

Thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That should work. I have used that exact command on mounted filesystems before with no problem. Can't you put the program somewhere that already has exec enabled?

Comment: The location is built into the installer, it's really annoying. This the latest FFMPEG. Thanks, I'm going to try it. Fingers crossed.